# How to connect FastAPI to frontend HTML

Tags: html, database, backend, fastapi

I am developing this project of a simple meme posting website where I take the `UserName`, `caption`, `Image URL` from the user and want to show all the memes on the home page of the website.

I am new to being a full stack developer, I am using FastAPI as backend and went through its documentation. So far I have been able to get the response from the HTML to the server via a Post request, but now I want to store the data in some database and send that data back to the Home page of the website. I tried finding tutorial videos but wasn't able to get the ones which could help me.
Any kind of help is appreciated.

Below is some code about how I am performing the current requests.

```
from fastapi import Request, status, BackgroundTasks
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from tutorial import app,templates
import time
from datetime import datetime
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional
class Record(BaseModel):
    name:str
    caption:str
    meme_type: Optional[str] = None
    img_meme:str

@app.post("/")
async def create_record(record: Record):
    background_tasks.add_task(_run_task,record)
    return record

def _run_task(name: str,caption: str,meme_type:str,img_meme: str):
    time.sleep(3)
    with open("memes.txt",mode="a") as file:
        now=datetime.now()
        content=f""" "Name":{name} \nCaption:{caption} \nURL:{img_meme} : now}\n"""
        file.write(content)
```

Answer (score 3):

**FastAPI documentation** has all the answers you need.

> I want to store the data in some database

- [SQL Databases](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/) - You can use any relational database you want. The documentation has example codes using SQLAlchemy.
- [Async SQL Databases](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/async-sql-databases/) - You can connect to your relational databases using async/await using a third-party package called [databases](https://github.com/encode/databases).
- [NoSQL Databases](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/nosql-databases/) - FastAPI can also be integrated with any NoSQL. The documentation has example codes using Couchbase.

> send that data back to the Home page of the website

- [HTMLResponse](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#html-response) - If your app is simple and straightforward.
- [Templates](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/templates/) - If you need template rendering. The documentation has example codes for Jinja2.

Comment: To add to the above, the creator of FastAPI made a fullstack application template that you can either take inspiration from or sinply generate your own project from, it's a bit more complex but it's well researched and maintained if you want a good starting point: https://github.com/tiangolo/full-stack-fastapi-postgresql